# Odoo display data in tree view from another model

Tags: odoo

Basically I need to create two custom models, one for manager entering data of sale, and another for employees to search for that sale and get like date of the sale and other data. I've created the first model, I enter my data and it displays as is should. Now I've ran into a problem because I have no idea how to display that data in another model. P.s. This is my first time working with odoo and I only doing this for a class so I kinda only need a solution. Thanks for the help.

```
from odoo import models, fields

class Uzsakymas(models.Model):

     _name = 'sales.uzsakymas'
     uzsakymonr = field.Integer('UzsakymoNr', required = True)

class Informacija(models.Model):

 _inherit = 'sales.uzsakymas'
 _name = 'sales.paieska'
```

Comment: Could you be more clear

Answer (score 0):

Actually according to your question, you need manager to create records of a sale model, and you need other employees to get those records and search between them. In odoo, you don't actually need to create two models for this, I will suggest you the modify the model permission so that only manager have create and edit permission, employees have only readonly permission. So using same `tree` and `form` view you created for manager, manager will be able to create and edit records, but employee roles will only be able to read data.